# a program which fits one box into another

Tags: java

This program is suppose to determine if one box could fit into another box. What is wrong with my code? It is giving me error when I compile it.

```
public class Box {
    int length = 0;
    int width = 0;
    int height = 0;


public int getLongestSide() {

    int max = length;
    if(width > max) {
        max = width;
    }
    if(height > max) {
        max = height;
    }
    return max;
}
public int getShortestSide() {

    int max = length;
    if(width > max) {
        max = width;
    }
    if(height > max) {
        max = height;
    }
```

This is the main class. I was thinking maybe I should write an if statement in the main class to compare the sides of the boxes to determine which one will fit into the other. Any help please.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class apples {

public static void main(String[] args) {
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

Box b = new Box();
Box b1 = new Box();

b.length = input.nextInt();
b.width = input.nextInt();
b.height = input.nextInt();

b1.length = input.nextInt();
b1.width = input.nextInt();
b1.height = input.nextInt();
b.getLongestSide();
b1.getShortestSide();

if(b.length > b1 && b.width > b1.width && b.height > b1.height) {
    System.out.println("b1 will fit in b");
}else {
    System.out.println("b will fit in b1");
      }
    }
 }
```

Comment: What is the error you are getting?

Comment: Check this `b.length > b1`, that's not valid. Also, you should declare your attributes as private and use getters and setters.

Comment: `b.length > b1` should be `b.length > b1.length`

Comment: b.getLongestSide();
b1.getShortestSide(); these two statements are useless, you should have something like int longside = b.getLongestSide();

Answer (score 1):

I see multiple issues here.

As Villat pointed out in his answer, you try to compare an `int` with an instance of your `Box` object. The relational comparator `>` expects two `int` or `char`, not an `Object`.

These statements are useless, since you do not use the output:

```
b.getLongestSide();
b1.getShortestSide();
```

And, just a little precision, your log in the else part of your method is not correct, you're not sure that b fits in b1.
To be sure, you should do something like this:

```
if(b.length > b1 && b.width > b1.width && b.height > b1.height)
{
    System.out.println("b1 will fit in b");
}
else if(b1.length > b.length && b.width > b1.width && b1.height > b.height)
{
    System.out.println("b will fit in b1");
}
else
{
    // Neither b fits in b1 nor b1 fits in b.
}
```

A more elegant way (and more object oriented) would be to create a method `boolean Box#fitsIn(Box)` in your `Box` object.

```
public class Box 
{
    int length = 0;
    int width = 0;
    int height = 0;

    // ...

    public boolean fitsIn(@Nonnull final Box otherBox)
    {
        return 
            length < otherBox.length
            && width < otherBox.width 
            && height < otherBox.height;
    }
}
```